# Create dynamic list (labels_true and labels_pred) from dictionaries of sets in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, scikit-learn

I have to create a list based on the below dictionaries
First dictionary is

```
groundTruth = {'1': ['IMG_0001.png', 'IMG_0002.png', '**IMG_0003.png**', '**IMG_0004.png**'], 
               '2': ['IMG_0020.png', 'IMG_0021.png', 'IMG_0022.png', 'IMG_0023.png'], 
               '3': ['IMG_0051.png', 'IMG_0052.png', 'IMG_0053.png', 'IMG_0054.png']}
```

Second dictionary is

```
clustering = {'1': ['IMG_0001.png', 'IMG_0002.png', '**IMG_0053.png**', '**IMG_0054.png**'], 
              '2': ['IMG_0020.png', 'IMG_0021.png', 'IMG_0022.png', 'IMG_0023.png'], 
              '3': ['**IMG_0003.png**', '**IMG_0004.png**', 'IMG_0051.png', 'IMG_0052.png']}
```

So, I have to create two lists labels_true which will consists of folder names like 1,2,3 and labels_pred which will check images name from clustering dictionary and check in groundtruth about in which folder that image is located and return that folder number into label_pred list.
For eg, in the below labels_pred we have two 3 in 1 1 because that two images are present in 1st folder in clustering dictionary.

Thus, how should I create this dynamic list in python. I am a new in Python. Appreciate your help. Thank you so much.

```
from sklearn import metrics
labels_true = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
labels_pred = [1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1]
metrics.adjusted_rand_score(labels_true, labels_pred)
```

Comment: why do some have `*` around the names?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making reversed dictionaries for start,

```
rground = {image:folder for folder, images in zip(clustering.keys(),clustering.values()) for image in images 
rcluster = {image:folder for folder, images in zip(clustering.keys(),clustering.values()) for image in images
```

Then since the order of images are in the first original dict you can get the values in a list and for your 2 lists do a reverse lookup with each dict like this

```
from itertools import chain
list_true = [rground[x] for x in chain.from_iterable(groundTruth.values())]
list_pred = [rcluster[x] for x in chain.from_iterable(groundTruth.values())]
```

note: the chain is for flattening the double list returned from values

Since the extra *** on some files are not clear what they do i assumed you striped them before, else you can do it in the above 4 lines anywhere necessary